# How to calculate a data in a column

Tags: sql

```
ACTNO CNAME      BNAME          AMOUNT ADATE
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
101   Anil       Vrce             1000 01-MAR-95
101   Sunil      Ajni             5000 04-JAN-96
102   Mehul      Karolbagh        3500 17-NOV-95
104   Madhura    Chandi           1200 17-DEC-95
105   Pramod     M.GRoad          3000 27-MAR-96
```

This is my table.

Now I want to add 10% interest to the data which is the under amount column

Comment: How to calculate (PTR)/100 I mean for the interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it.

```
update MyTable set AMOUNT  = AMOUNT * 1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward `update` statement should do the trick:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    amount = amount * 1.1
```